# Prove that the set is convex and closed

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^d$. Assume that the set $$`\{`(x_1, x_1+x_2, x_1+x_2+x_3, \ldots, x_1+\ldots, x_d): (x_1, \ldots, x_d)\in A `\}`$$
is closed and convex. Is it true that
$$$`\{`(x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots, x_d): (x_1, \ldots, x_d)\in A `\}`$$
closed and convex?

Attempt: I was wondering if one could define a linear map from the pervious set to the latter set. Linear map preserves close and convex properties.

Comment: Be careful: Linear maps preserve convexity but in general not closed sets (in your case, the linear map has a continuous inverse which salvages the argument). For an example: $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$, $(x,y)\mapsto x$ is clearly linear, $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2: x\ge 0, xy\ge 1\}$ is closed and convex but its image is $(0,\infty)$ which is not closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea of defining a linear map is great. Consider the $d \times d$ matrix whose $n$th column is the vector $\sum_{k=1}^n e_k$, where $\{e_k\}$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^d$. Then this matrix maps the set $A$ to the set $\{(x_1, x_1 + x_2, \dotsc, x_1 + x_2 + \dotsc + x_d): (x_1, x_2, \dotsc, x_d) \in A\}$. This matrix will be an upper triangular matrix, so we can calculate its determinant as the product of the diagonal entries, which are all equal to 1, so the determinant of this matrix is 1. So then the inverse of this matrix exists, and the inverse of this matrix maps the set $\{(x_1, x_1 + x_2, \dotsc, x_1 + x_2 + \dotsc + x_d): (x_1, x_2, \dotsc, x_d) \in A\}$ to $A$, and we can conclude that $A$ is closed and convex as you said.

Hope this helps! Let me know if anything is unclear.